# React/Redux: Component renders with old props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using useEffects return() to clean up the state data in Redux when leaving a page. However, when changing view to another page, a child component that fetches new data still shows the old data from Redux for a short time before the new data shows up. The child component fetches data with a useEffect(), with an empty dependency list.

The clean up useEffect looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () =>  {
      props.clearState()
    }
  }, [])
```

Where clearState() resets the redux-store to its initial values. The Redux Devtools shows that the state actually is cleared, but the child-component still renders with old props for a short time. I read that useEffect is asynchronous, could it be that the useEffect therefore is to slow? And how would you solve this without using the return() from useEffect?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If the data is fetched when the child mounts, and is thrown away when the child unmounts, why even bother storing it in anything other than local component state?

Comment: You could turn the component into a class component and try componentWillUnmount to see if that makes a difference. But I agree with the comment above, better use local component state for this.